# Deployment strategy for angular frontend and dotnetcore backend with ssl in one Linux server

Tags: angular, linux, .net-core, reverse-proxy, web-deployment

Requirements - Angular and dotnetcore Webapi in one Linux server with ssl.
how to configure the webserver and angular in this case. should i have a reverse proxy or use
different public ip address for both apps (can get more than one public ip and ssl cert.) ? should i use apache or nginx ?
what is the best deployment strategy. any expert in angular and dotnetcore webapi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we do it like this. There is a web app on domain.com. For .net core, we configure it as api.domain.com, for example. We get separate SSL certificates for main domain and sub domain. We use nginx for publishing. I highly recommend it. And we automate publishing with dev.azure.com.

Comment: Did you deploy your webapp and .netcore on the same server ?